# Prove that $g(x)=cx$ for some constant c

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, recurrence-relations, functional-equations

> Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers in the interval $(0,1/2)$ and let $g$ be a continuous real-valued function so that $g(g(x)) = ag(x)+bx$ for all real x. Prove that $g(x)=cx$ for some constant c.

Let $x_0$ be a real number. One can show that g is injective easily. To see why g is surjective, observe that $g$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing by continuity and injectivity. g cannot tend to a finite limit as n tends to infinity since otherwise $g(g(x))-ag(x)=bx$ would be bounded and similarly g cannot tend to a finite limit as $x\to -\infty$. By the IVT and monotonicity, g is surjective. Now we can define the sequence $x_n$ by $x_n = g(x_{n-1})$ for $n\ge 1$ and $x_{n-1} = g^{-1}(x_n)$ for $n\leq 0$. One can then observe that the roots of the characteristic equation of this sequence are $r_1,r_2=(a\pm \sqrt{a^2+4b})/2$. So $x_n = c_1r_1^n + c_2 r_2^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

> I get that the formula holds for nonnegative n, but for $n > 0,x_{-n} - a x_{-n-1}-bx_{-n-2} = 0,$ so wouldn't the characteristic equation for $(x_{-n})_{n>0}$ be $bx^2 +ax-1=0$? This seems to lead to a different formula for $x_n$.

Edit: Note that if $x$ is a root of $x^2-ax+b,$ then $b\neq 0\Rightarrow x\neq 0$ and so $1/x$ is a root of $bx^2+ax-1.$ Conversely, if $x$ is a root of $bx^2 + ax-1$, then $1/x$ is a root of $x^2-ax+b$. This generalizes to arbitrary polynomials when one reverses the coefficients. For $n\ge -1$, $x_{-n} = c_1' r_1^{-n} + c_2' r_2^{-n}$ for some constants $c_1'$ and $c_2'$. Then the values for $x_0$ and $x_1$ show that the coefficients for the roots of $x_{-n}$ are indeed $c_1$ and $c_2$.

> But how can one analyze this to conclude that $g$ has the required form? I was thinking of taking limits and using the facts that $r_1 > 0>r_2, 1 >|r_1|>|r_2|$.

Comment: See also [Continuous functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f\big(f(x)\big)=rf(x)+sx$ and $r,s \in (0, 1/2).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3750425). (probably a better duplicate but newer, I can't change my vote though)

Comment: @Sil can you just confirm whether my justification for the sequence is correct? I'm only assuming that for a general sequence $x_n $ defined for $n\ge k$ so that $x_n = g(x_{n-1},x_{n-2})$ for some linear function g, $x_n = A r_1^n + B r_2^n$ for $n\ge k$ where A and B are constants and $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the roots of the characteristic equation. My confusion is that I can't seem to prove from the definition that $x_{-1} = c_1/r_1 + c_2/r_2$ (i.e. I can't prove $g(x_{-1}) = x_0$).

Comment: I think it's correct, the reasoning with reciprocal polynomial. Though you could always solve the new recurrence and find their $r_1,r_2$ are just reciprocals of the original as well.